# how to pull latest update into local by using last commit hash?

Tags: git, branch

I am trying to pull latest update from remote branch.

To accomplish this task, I change from `mybranch` to `master` and then I pull the latest commits,
However these actions does not retrieve any error nor any actualization in local branch.

Here's what I got:

```
git checkout master
git pull   # not retrieving latest update
```

When checking what's going on in the branch here's what it returns:

```
git branch -a -vv
```

Output:

```
  mybranch               4e09bec [origin/mybranch] adding modules
* master                   0ec6980 [origin/master] adding elmo
  remotes/origin/HEAD      -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/mybranch 4e09bec adding modules
  remotes/origin/master    0ec6980 adding elmo
```

By knowing this I would like to pull the latest `master` commit by using hash name `0ec6980` in order to retrieve latest commit.
How could I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your branch output in fact does show that your local `master` branch is up to date with `origin/master`, the latter which is supposed to track the true remote `master` branch.  That being said, if you wanted to update your local `master` up to a certain specific commit in the remote branch, you may just fetch and the merge with that SHA-1, e.g.

```
# from local master
git fetch origin
get merge 0ec6980
```

Note that this might be considered a somewhat atypical thing to do (I don't recall ever having the need to do this).

Comment: Indeed, it's really atypical, maybe it's a cloud-platform issue, anyways thanks for your help!